# ¿Como obtener dos gráficos de caja en la misma salida en R?

Tags: r

Quisiera obtener dos gráficos de caja en una sola salida(imagen), por ejemplo si usamos el siguiente codigo

```
data(iris)
boxplot(iris$Sepal.Length,iris$Sepal.Width)
```

obtenemos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quisiera es obtener cada una de las gráficas con sus propios ejes pero en una sola imagen, como esto:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A que te refieres con "una sola imagen"? ya que ahora tienes una sola imagen con dos cajas, ¿Quiere una sola caja por imagen?

Comment: seria generar dos gráficos usando por ejemplo `boxplot(iris$Sepal.Length); boxplot(iris$Sepal.Width)` pero esto produce dos imágenes, lo que hago después es pegarlas por ejemplo en paint para que una quede a la derecha y la otra a la izquierda y esa seria la salida(imagen) que quiero obtener en R.

Comment: Algo así: `boxplot(iris$Sepal.Length, ylim = c(2, 8));boxplot(iris$Sepal.Width, ylim = c(2, 8))` tal vez?

Comment: cuando corrí el código del comentario obtuve dos imágenes. He agregado a la pregunta la imagen editada en paint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te entendí correctamente, lo que buscas es algo como esto:

```
limites <- range(min(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width),
                 max(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)
)

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
boxplot(iris$Sepal.Length, ylim = limites)
boxplot(iris$Sepal.Width, ylim = limites)
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ten en cuenta que en este casos los valores de `y` son en la misma medida y relativamente cercanos, por lo que se puede unificar este eje en los dos gráficos.

Usamos `par()` para establecer opciones del gráfico, en este caso `mfrow` para indicar que queremos un gráfico organizado en una sola fila y dos columnas